# Differentiating an equation in index notation and expressing it in matrix form

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative

I'm trying to follow the derivation of equation (6) from equation (5) in [1].
Basically, the starting point is the following:

$$
Q = \sum_n \sum_m p_{mn} || x_n - y_m - g_m W ||^2,
$$

where:

- $p_{mn}$ is the $(m,n)$ element of matrix $P\in R^{M\times N}$
- $x_n$ is the $n$-th row of matrix $X\in R^{N\times 3}$
- $y_m$ is the $m$-th row of matrix $Y\in R^{M\times 3}$
- $g_m$ is the $m$-th row of the symmetric matrix $G\in R^{M\times M}$, so $G=G^T$
- $W\in R^{M\times 3}$

The idea is to find the $W$ that minimizes $Q$.
Therefore, the authors differentiate $Q$ wrt $W$:

$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial W} = -2 G \left(PX - d(P1) Y - d(P1) GW\right),
$$

where $1$ is a vector of all ones and $d(v)$ is a diagonal matrix made up of the elements in vector $v$.

The problem is that I can't seem to make sense of how they derive this expression from the previous one.
I would really appreciate it if anyone could shed some light over this.

Thanks!

---

[1] Myronenko, A., Song, X., & Carreira-Perpiñán, M. Á. (2007). Non-rigid point set registration: Coherent point drift. Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems, 1009–1016. https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.493&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative writes
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{W}}
= -2 \sum_{m,n} P_{mn}
\mathbf{g}_m^T
\left( 
\mathbf{x}_n - \mathbf{y}_m - \mathbf{g}_m \mathbf{W} 
\right)
$$

Regarding the first matrix term,
we have
$$
\sum_{m,n} P_{mn}
\mathbf{g}_m^T
\mathbf{x}_n
=
\sum_{m} 
\mathbf{g}_m^T
\sum_n P_{mn} \mathbf{x}_n =
\mathbf{G}^T (\mathbf{PX} )
$$

Regarding the second matrix term,
we have
$$
\sum_{m,n} P_{mn}
\mathbf{g}_m^T
\mathbf{y}_m
=
\sum_{m} 
\mathbf{g}_m^T
\left(\sum_n P_{mn} \right) \mathbf{y}_m =
\mathbf{G}^T \mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{P}\mathbf{1}_N) \mathbf{Y}
$$

The thirs term is similar.

Note that the result is similar to what you expected BUT with $\mathbf{G}^T$ instead of $\mathbf{G}$ for the most-left matrix.

Comment: Great @Steph, thank you! I was getting the dimensions of the final expression mixed up because I was not interpreting the $m$ summation correctly. And yes, you are right about $G^T$, I forgot to mention that $G$ is symmetric.